# Is it possible to split up different types of socket.io connections?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm currently reading about socket.io, and while it looks like a solid library, every example I can find of it stores every event in the one (index.js) file.

Is it possible to split these up (for example, having events linked to particular routing instructions)? Having every communication across a site all stored in one section of a page feels like encapsulation hell.

Comment: It's possible to split it up. If you want better answers, please post code.